# SQL Update Statement in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

Trying to get this query to work in MS Access.

```
Update Network.Location=Enclave.Location Where Enclave.Site=No AND 
Network.AlternateLocation=Enclave.Location Where Enclave.Site=Yes
```

I'm not sure how to get this to do exactly what I want which is  store Enclave location  in network location if the enclave site field is No and if yes store encalve location in alternate location, meaning it would store a blank value in network location in that row.

**Key fields update**:

```
Update Network InnerJoin Enclave On Network.ID=Enclave.ID Set 
Network.Location=Enclave.Location Where Enclave.Site=No AND 
Network.AlternateLocation=Enclave.Location Where Enclave.Site=Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Network Inner Join Enclave ON Network.ID=Enclave.ID
SET Network.Location = IIF(Enclave.Site=False, Enclave.Location, ""),
Network.AlternateLocation = IIF(Enclave.Site=True, Enclave.Location, "")
```

Note: I haven't tried this & guess, this should work.
Also, I have assumed that you will want the field to be updated with blank, if it doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: you are the man..I knew it was something like this just couldn't find out the if conition syntax

Answer (score 2):

You should break the command in two:

```
Update Network SET Location=Enclave.Location Where Enclave.Site=No;
Update Network SET AlternateLocation=Enclave.Location Where Enclave.Site=Yes;
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the tables involved?
I've just realized there are two of them

Comment: and it seems as if I can't have two update statements in one update query in access. because when I try to close the query i get an error at the second update

Comment: I'd like to know the key fields to join the tables:

UPDATE Network n SET Location = e.location from enclave e where n.id = e.id and e.Site = NO

Comment: I'm not access expert, but can't you create two query objects instead of one?

Comment: No you can join queries that return records, but you can only have one update clause in access. so having two separate update clauses will not work unless I have two different query files which I don't want to do