# Please help me make this Access 2007 Friendly

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007, sql-update

I asked a friend to hellp me with an issue I was having with my Access Database since I haven't programmed in years, and here's what he replied with:

> Let me toss an example out just to make sure I'm looking at this
>   right.  You start with a record with ID 1.  This gets renewed, and the
>   system generates a new record with ID 2, and brings along the old ID
>   of 1 in the RenewalOf field, and so on for future renewals.  If that
>   is correct, and each record is only allowed to be referenced once (so
>   there will only ever be one record with ID of 1 in the RenewalOf
>   field), then the following should work:

This bit of code didn't work:

```
UPDATE
tblSold
SET
RenewedToID = RenewalRecord.SoldID
FROM
tblSold
INNER JOIN tblSold RenewalRecord ON
tblSold.SoldID = RenewalRecord.RenewalOf
```

> Not sure what is allowed in your SQL queries, but this is basic and
>   should be fine.  You can also add in some criteria to only update
>   records where the RenewedToID field is blank, or only for one record
>   if you are processing this just after you add a new record.  You can
>   check to make sure this is going to work by running the following:

But this did:

```
SELECT
tblSold.SoldID
,RenewalRecord.SoldID
FROM
tblSold
INNER JOIN tblSold RenewalRecord ON
tblSold.SoldID = RenewalRecord.RenewalOf
```

> This will list the original ID along with the renewal ID, i.e. the one
>   that will be put in the original record.  Let me know if this works or
>   if you have any issues with it.

Can you help me make his first code snippet work in Access 2007?

Comment: What is the error returned from your first query?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to rearrange the update slightly for Access:

```
UPDATE
tblSold
INNER JOIN tblSold RenewalRecord ON
tblSold.SoldID = RenewalRecord.RenewalOf
SET
tblSold.RenewedToID = RenewalRecord.SoldID
```

Some other SO answers showing this type of syntax:
[SQL Update Statement in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046195/sql-query-in-ms-access)
[How to create a correlated update subquery in MS-Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322504/how-to-create-a-correlated-update-subquery-in-ms-access)